# Django cache_page()

Tags: python, django, caching

How to use cache on CBV?
I added this to my settings.py
`CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:8000',
    }
}`
My urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<resolution>[0-9]+x[0-9]+)/$', cache_page(60 * 60)(ImageView.as_view()))
```

And this is my views.py:

```
class ImageView(ListView):
model = DummyImage
template_name = 'dummy_images/images.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """Split resolution string by 'x' character."""
    width = self.kwargs['resolution'].split('x')[0]
    height = self.kwargs['resolution'].split('x')[1]

    dummy_images = DummyImage.objects.all()
    dummy_images_counter = DummyImage.objects.all().count()

    random_image = get_object_or_404(DummyImage, pk=dummy_images[random.randrange(0, dummy_images_counter)].id)
    context = {'width': width, 'height': height, 'img': random_image, }

    return context
```

I want to save random_image in cache using memcache and display it in one of my templates.How do I do that? I spent hours reading documentation and answers on stack but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You give us conflicting messages here. In the title of your question, you state that you are looking info on Django's `cache_page`. However, in the question itself you mention that you need to cache model instance. If the latter is the case, you just have to use `cache.set` and `cache.set`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#basic-usage

Comment: I think you may be right with cache.set() and cache.get(), but it doesn't work for some reason. I try to test it using python.manage.py shell and when I run cache.get(''test'') it doesn't return anything.Not even "None".When I use cache.set("test", "Hello, world", 30), I can see on my server that it has been set.Could it be some instalation problem regarding settings.py?

Comment: First of all, "doesn't even return None" is simply untrue - if a function doesn't have a return statement, it is equivalent to a `return None` statement. Secondly, if `cache.set` works, but `cache.get` doesn't, I would first of all check keys and timeout. Way you worded it, I presume you used  30-second timeout for that cache key in your code. Are you sure that's enough for your purpose? Try using something along the line of minutes and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Still I can't see any output from cache.get() and server acts like nothing happened.

Comment: I got it working by changing a line in settings.py LOCATION to port 11211.Now whenever the image is picked randomly from database and I save it in cache for let's say 10 seconds, it doesn't disappear. I want to get a new picture every 10 seconds, how to do that?

Comment: So, turns out, it was a configuration issue, after all. However, I don't understand how "I can see on my server that it has been set" (from your comment) would even work.

Comment: It's not how stackoverflow works. What you are asking now is a totally separate question, so you should post it as separate question.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help and attention.